# Atomic insert of data in micro service architecture + NoSql database [Data consistency in Micro service architecture]

Tags: database-design, cassandra, architecture, microservices, nosql

I have 3 services A, B, C.

Service A receives a request from client. Then A prepares a data for its own database, service B and C. Basically A is coo-ordinator.

1. A insert data in its database

If it is success

2. post request B's data to service B and B insert data in its DB

If it is success

3. then post request C's data to service C and C insert data in its DB

If anything fails at any step, we have to revert all data inserted.

I am using Cassandra NoSQL DB.

**Now i need a generic solution for all cases that could happen like :**

- I.

  Suppose C is inserting data (in progress), in the mean time, some read query R on A-database reads the inserted data. After few millisec, C fails to insert, but R already read the false data which would be reverted soon.

What to do in this case?
--> change the DB design, such that this kind of condition would never happen??

- II.

  What if service C data insert fails, and service B have application server downtime so it couldn't revert??

Comment: That sounds like quite a problem to solve! You can batch operations in Cassandra but beware it can come at a cost of performance: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/latest/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html. It might be easier to think about how you are updating and modelling the data trying to make your updates idempotent and structuring things this way instead of breaking into "services"

Comment: @markc the services are already being created and they have strict data-access rules. So, the option that i left with is only change data-model i think.

Comment: LWTs as mentioned in one of the answers below are an option here. It sounds like the services do have some connection between them as it seems they are aware of the previous success update. However CAS (compare and set) operations can become very expensive very quickly. One thing I would advise is make sure you test at scale one you reach a satisfactory solution. I cannot stress enough how important this is. The amount of times I've seen systems fail only when scaled out - I've lost count!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Batch Query for this. There is a parameter in yaml file to configure the batch size.
batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb : 50 is default.

Answer (score 0):

If your services are completely independent you will have a hard time when using cassandra. You are asking for a transaction around the three services all using their own data storage.

Cassandra supports only lightweight transactions by its own - see http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlLtwtTransactions.html

You can go and implement your own 2-Phase-Commit:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paxos_(computer_science)

Comment: how to implement 2PC for MSA + NoSql DB.

As i know the normal 2PC hold the cohort resources until it is complete or abort.

But in NoSql there are no locks. Is there any solution?

Comment: One idea i could think about is tracking state for every primary key in the services and a field in your data as well as using callbacks and timeouts.

Comment: @Mandraenke good point; LWTs are an option, however CAS operations although supported in Cassandra can suffer from performance drop off. I mentioned this above but wanted to reiterate here in context. If you use LWTs please test this at scale!